# Jade Template Trouble accessing Values from view data

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I've passed an object to my jade template from express:

```
connection.invokeQuery(sqlStatement, function(rows){
    res.render('index', { title: 'App', companies: rows});
});
```

here's my template

```
extends layout
block content
    h1= title
    div
        each company in companies
           p #{company.City}
```

that works, I can render a city list.  But I'm not sure how to get at the root property or sub properties and objects within an object with jade.

For example lets say the json for company was this:

```
   [{
        companyName: 'Apple',
            City: 'Milwaukee',
            State: 'WI ',
            StateName: 'Wisconsin',
            Country: 'United States',
            Region: 'North America',
            PostalCode: '53201-0371'},
            {
               Website: 'www.apple.com',
               ....
            },
        ... and so on

    }]
```

I tried company.**companyName** and it doesn't work.

Also how would I reference the property "Website"?  It's in another object below in this array.

Comment: What error do you get using companyName?

Comment: Could you do console.log(rows) before res.render and show the output?

Comment: it renders nothing just empty p tags if I do company.companyName.  I end up with <p></p> when I view source

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing here, you have multiple objects inside an array. You wouldn't be able to access "Website" as it is in another object. The `each` statement is iterating over the array containing your objects. You could access it in the second iteration of your `each` statement, but no other properties of the first object. If you wanted access to that value, it must be a part of the same object.

Comment: fixed the space, although I didn't know that mattered.  I also tried p= company.companyName, same deal.  Again company.City works fine

Comment: sorry what is a javascript-y expression, y stands for what?

Comment: My apologies. I fixed the answer to actually answer your question.